# How to convert results (urls) from string to DataFrame for Pandas to_excel?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

My Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from numpy.lib.function_base import extract
import requests
import pandas as pd

Scraper2Excel = "C:\\Users\\Ashley\\FromPython3.xlsx"

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(Scraper2Excel, engine='xlsxwriter')

READ = "C:\\Users\\Ashley\\URLs List.xlsx"
Tickers1 = pd.read_excel(READ, sheet_name='Tickers', header=None)
Tickers = Tickers1.values.ravel()
print(Tickers)

UniformResourceLocators = pd.read_excel(READ, sheet_name= 'URLs', header=None, skiprows=1)
UniformResourceLocatorsTitles = pd.read_excel(READ, sheet_name='URLs', header=None, nrows=1).values[0]
UniformResourceLocators.columns = UniformResourceLocatorsTitles

URLs = UniformResourceLocators['Company News URL']
tick = UniformResourceLocators['Tickers']

startrow =0

for i in Tickers:
    s = Tickers1.loc[(Tickers1[0]==i)]
    print(s)
    s.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow= startrow, startcol= 0, header=False, index=False)
    startrow += 1

    url = URLs.loc[(tick==i)]
    print(url)
    
    for i in url:
        html_text = requests.get(i).text
        chickennoodle = soup(html_text, 'html.parser')
    
        for link in chickennoodle.find_all('a'):
            my_links = (link.get('href'))
            


            print(my_links)
```

I get stuck here. `my_links` prints a bunch of URLs in a string format, and I'm wanting to output them to an excel file.  I haven't been able to find a way to convert it to a DataFrame so pandas will let me use `to_excel`.  I'm very novice so thanks for any help.

```
             
            #df = my_links??
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet2', startrow= startrow, startcol=0, header=False, index=False)
            startrow += 1


writer.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is initiate an empty list before your for loop and then append 'my_links' to that list within your loop.

Then at the end of your code , you can convert that list to a column of your df before exporting to excel.
Something like

```
mylinksList=[]
df=pd.DataFrame()

for i in url:
        html_text = requests.get(i).text
        chickennoodle = soup(html_text, 'html.parser')
    
        for link in chickennoodle.find_all('a'):
            my_links = (link.get('href'))
            mylinksList.append(my_links)



df['links']=pd.Series(mylinksList)
```

Comment: A nice and fancy addition would be to add links in a string format as following
str(f'=HYPERLINK("https://websitename.com{link_adress}", "{link_text}")')

Comment: thanks this helped tons! I ended up doing 

mylinksList.append(my_links)
a = pd.DataFrame(mylinksList)
a.to_excel...